# Compare different versions of PDF documents in SAS

Tags: sas, adobe

I would like to compare PDF documents created in SAS with their previous versions as they are created. I'm wondering if anyone can provide some idea on how to achieve this. It might involve calling Adobe reader to do the comparison from SAS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sorts of differences are you trying to detect? It would be much easier to compare the datasets used to generate the PDFs rather than the PDFs themselves.

Comment: Yes I agree it would be easier to compare the datasets. The point is that I'd like to highlight these differences, texts, numbers, in the final PDF document. So if you can think of a way to achieve this I'd be happy to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether this tool works on your platform, but it looks as though it does exactly what you want:

https://vslavik.github.io/diff-pdf/

It takes command-line input so it should be trivial to call it from SAS.